# Set containing open ball and contained in closed ball has the same boundary

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm having some difficult time trying to figure out how to prove that if $U$ is an open unit ball and $\overline{U}$ is a closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $U\subseteq A\subseteq \overline{U}$ then the boundary of $A$ is the same as the boundary of $U$ or $\overline{U}$. Would definitely appreciate a hint.

My attempt:

$\mbox{bd}(\overline{U}) = \overline{U}\setminus U \supseteq \overline{U}\setminus A \supseteq \overline{U}\setminus U \supseteq \overline{U}\setminus \overline{U} = \emptyset$, so that $\overline{U}\setminus A = \mbox{bd}(\overline{U})=\mbox{bd}(U)$, which implies that bd$(A)= \mbox{bd}(U)$.

Unfortunately, my argument does not appear to be convincing enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that $U=B(0,1)$. Since $\overline U$ is closed, we have that $\overline A\subset\overline U$. Since $U$ is an open ball, every point of $U$ is an interior point of $A$. Hence, $\partial A\subset \overline U\setminus U=\{x:\,|x|=1\}=\partial U$. Taking $x\in\partial U$, for every $r>0$, $B(x,r)$ intersects both $U\subset A$ and $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \overline U\subset \mathbb{R}^n\setminus A$ and so $x\in \partial A$.

Comment: You say that:
1. "Since $U$ is an open ball, every point of $U$ is an interior point of $A$." 2. "Hence, $\partial A\subset \overline U\setminus U=\{x:\,|x|=1\}=\partial U$."

But I don't understand how (2) follows from (1). Can you please clarify?

Comment: A boundary point cannot be an interior point. To be on the boundary means that every ball centered at the point intersects both the set and the complement of the set. This cannot happen for an interior point, since there is one ball centered at the point and entirely contained in the set.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $cl(A)  \subseteq cl(B(0,1))$ from the fact that the closure of the set $A$ is the smallest closed set that contains $A$.

Also $B(0,1) \subseteq A \Rightarrow cl(B(0,1)) \subseteq cl(A)$

Thus $cl(B(0,1))=cl(A)$

Also  $int(B(0,1))=B(0,1)=int(A)$

Thus $bd(B(0,1))=cl(B(0,1))$ \ $B(0,1)=cl(A)$ \ $int(A)=bd(A)$